# What is the average speed for the entire trip?

Tags: physics

A train leaves on station 80 miles/hour for 3.5 hours and 70 miles/hour for 2 hours to reach it's destination. What was the average seed for the entire trip.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: im sorry sir.. yes i'll do it next time but this problem i really don't know the formula thanks..

Comment: No need to apologize! It's just always encouraged to see your work so finding the answer can be a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Average speed}&=\frac{\text{total distance traveled}}{\text{total time traveled}}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{80\cdot 3.5+70\cdot 2}{3.5+2}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{420}{5.5}\\[5pt]
&=76.\overline{36}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: thanks a lot sir

Comment: not sir. and your welcome :-)

Comment: @ervx "Ser", then? :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the total distance travelled (by summing up the distances of each "leg" at a different speed), then divide by the total time for the trip.

Comment: thanks sir its a big help to me